# How to match codec in cassandra for list<varchar> <-> java.util.List

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a column `info map<text, frozen<list<text>>>` in cassandra.
Trying to retrieve this map data in java from the below code.

```
for (Row row : conn.getSession().execute("SELECT info FROM demo.variants where chr = '" +chr + "' and pos = " + pos)) {
    Map<String, List> map = row.getMap("info", String.class, List.class);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

When doing this way, I am getting the error

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [list<varchar> <-> java.util.List]
```

I could not figure out how to resolve this nested type codec exception. What are the ways to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`TypeTokens.listOf(TypeToken)`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/TypeTokens.html#listOf-java.lang.Class-) utility method to create a `TypeToken<List<String>>` and use that as the element type to retrieve the map, i.e.:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> info = row.getMap("info", TypeToken.of(String.class), TypeTokens.listOf(String.class));
```